# SharePoint Designer workflow Call HTTP service Get Top Level Site List Data

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I have created SharePoint Designer Workflow. In that, I want to create workflow Task and assign the task to different users. I have One top level site that contains the Users list. I have to get all the users from the Top level site and create a task and assign that task to that particular user.

So for this, I have tried to get the users data from the Call HTTP service of the SharePoint Designer workflow. I can the data of current site loop through all the data, but when I make service call to the **Top level** site from the **SubSite** then it gives me the "**Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource**". How to solve this particular issue. I have tried this with the Admin account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to permission issue.

Can you please write HTTP request inside "**App Step**" in SharePoint. App step is used for achieve **Impersonation** functionality in SharePoint Designer Workflow.

How to enable App Step in SharePoint Designer Workflow please check below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

Comment: Thanks :-) it works for me. My problem has been resolved